# no response from a form

Tags: php, forms, redirect, token

I'm working on a tokens redirection system for my project.
This is what I want to do: 
User insert token => the web site searches for an entry with this token and when he finds it he takes the test name => redirect to the test page.

But I have a problem, when I press the button I don't have any reaction.

This is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['redibtn'])) {redit();}

function redit(){ if (isset($_POST['redibtn'])) {    
    global $db, $token, $errors;

    // grap form values
    $token = e($_POST['token']);

    // attempt login if no errors on form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {

      $query = "SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE Token='$token' LIMIT 1";
      $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

      if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
        // check if user is admin or user
        $choix = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
        if ($choix['test'] == 'Integration') {

          header('location: integrationffg/test.php');     
        }else{

          header('location: aaa.php');
        }
      }else {     
      }
    }   
  }   
}


<form  >
  <center>
<p>Passer un exam :</p>
  </center>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Token</span>
  <input required type="text" name="token" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex. b2f56acc7c212ee5af432e9794ccdbef" >
</div>

<br>
<center>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="redibtn">Zuu</button>
</center>

</form>
```

My database table:

[image]

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Button type button doesn't send form, you need button type submit))) `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="redibtn">Zuu</button>`

Comment: Default method used when submitting a form is get. Add `method="post"` to the `<form>` attribute and it should be ok.

Comment: @Heyne It will not help, while he doesn't have submit button

Comment: The whole thing isn't working.

Comment: you need to close php tag before form `?>`

Comment: ... and to open it first. See? Same thing 'round.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a working version of your script below, with a few modifications made to it.

Starting off with the first if: instead of having a named button and a check on every request if the key exists in the `$_POST`-array, you can just check if the request type is POST.

Going further on I've added a strict comparison to the `count($errors)` check to really make sure this is a `0` and nothing else.

In the opening form tag I've also added the `method` attribute, to ensure it is sent as POST and not as a GET request and the first if actually works.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    redit();
}

function redit()
{
    global $db, $token, $errors;

    // grap form values
    $token = e($_POST['token']);

    // attempt login if no errors on form
    if (count($errors) === 0) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE Token='$token' LIMIT 1";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
            // check if user is admin or user
            $choix = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
            if ($choix['test'] == 'Integration') {
                header('location: integrationffg/test.php');
                exit;
            } else {
                header('location: aaa.php');
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            // Something went wrong. You should state that.
        }
    }
}
?>

<form method="post">
    <center>
        <p>Passer un exam:</p>
    </center>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Token</span>
        <input required type="text" name="token" class="form-control" placeholder=
        "Ex. b2f56acc7c212ee5af432e9794ccdbef">
    </div>

    <br>
    <center>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Zuu</button>
    </center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I hope it can help you:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['redibtn'])) {
    redit();
}

function redit()
{
    global $db, $token, $errors;

    // grap form values
    $token = e($_POST['token']);

    // attempt login if no errors on form
    if (!count($errors)) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE Token='$token' LIMIT 1";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
            // check if user is admin or user
            $choix = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
            if ($choix['test'] == 'Integration') {
                header('location: integrationffg/test.php');
            } else {
                header('location: aaa.php');
            }
        } else {

        }
    }    
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <center>
        <p>Passer un exam :</p>
    </center>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Token</span>
        <input required type="text" name="token" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Ex. b2f56acc7c212ee5af432e9794ccdbef">
    </div>
    <br>
    <center>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="redibtn">Zuu</button>
    </center>
</form>
```

You have few issues in your code

- if there is no method in form, it will send by method `GET`, but you try `$_POST`
- Furm must have submit button
- Close php tag before start html `?>`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" name="test" id="test" /><br/>

<?php

function redit()
{
   echo "Your redit function on button click is working";
}
if(array_key_exists('test',$_POST)){
   redit();
}
?>
```